# How do I calculate the number of members in a limited Fibonacci series?

Tags: algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

Looking for an algorithm that will give me the number of members that will result from calculating a Fibonacci series, given a particular limit.

For example, if I start the series at 1 and limit my results to <= 10000, determine the number of members such a Fibonacci series will contain. (I am writing some software that builds a Fibonacci series to a given limit: Before the calculation begins, it would be more efficient to know in advance how much memory I need to allocate for a container that will hold all the resulting members of the series)

Comment: The "Binet" [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) for Fibonacci numbers may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formula
$$F_n = \left\lfloor\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Say your bound is $N$.
You then want to find the first $n$ such that 
$$\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}+\frac{1}{2}\ge N+1$$
which can be rephrased as
$$n\ge \log_\varphi\sqrt5\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Thus, given $N$ you can take
$$n=\left\lceil\log_\varphi\sqrt5+\log_\varphi\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\rceil-1$$
to be the last $n$ such that $F_n\le N$

Comment: This looks good but I'm still working on converting it into Golang so I can test it out - need a bit of help, I'm not very familiar with GoLang math libraries and representations.